# Laravel php artisan, problem with container

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to connect laravel with my db the problem is php artisan doesn't found the class Cash.store.

Hello,

> In Container.php line 730:
>   Class cache.store does not exist

I try to change the container.php and cache.php thanks to google but nothing changes.

My container.php

```
   namespace Illuminate\Container;
use Closure;
use ArrayAccess;
use LogicException;
use ReflectionClass;use ReflectionParameter;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Container\Container as ContainerContract;
```

And my cache.php

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
```

Thank you for taking your time :)
Ps : I can't write Hello as first word.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you want but does the model Cash have a controller?

Comment: Plz check the storage directory permissions, should be writable by the webserver

Comment: what is value of env variable `CACHE_DRIVER` in Your `.env` file?

Comment: So the value for CACHE_DRIVER is file

Comment: I have a UserController :
<?php 
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
 
  class UserController extends Controller {
   /** * Show a list of all users of the application. * * @return Response */
    public function index() {
     $value = Cache::get('key'); // 
   }
  }

Comment: How I can check that ?

Answer (score 0):

how i understood you try to save your cache in db, if you all doing right try clean cache, if it won't help try to get error by dd() on each step.

Comment: When I write in the console : php artisan optimize
He say the same message :
In Container.php line 730:

  Class cache.store does not exist      /////                                                                                            
Where I can write dd()